# AngularJS: Sending requests via $resource with array type parameters (checkboxes, multiselects etc.)

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angularjs-controller

I have problems trying to use the $resource library in AngularJS to send a properly serialized GET request when there is an array of checkboxes (client_status) in my GET parameters.

This is the code I have right now in my controller:

```
$scope.filters = {
    client_status: ["CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER", "CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE"],
    client_reference: "e"
}

$scope.records = Client.get($scope.filters, function(data){
    ...
}
```

The above will send the following GET request:

```
f.json?client_reference=e&client_status=CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER,CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE
```

However, from what I understand, the above seems like it's not the correct format.  Can someone guide me a bit here?  The following is what I expect:

```
f.json?client_reference=e&client_status%5B%5D=CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE&client_status%5B%5D=CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using $resource by changing the client_status to 'client_status[]' like this:

```
$scope.filters = {
  'client_status[]': ["CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER", "CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE"],
  client_reference: "e"
}
```

I created a plunker for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/QXIaY8XlMUfOy7RNMKKv?p=info

I put a dummy URL in there so if you use Firebug or Chrome dev tools when you run the plunker, you will see the request to http://example.com/api showing the correct addition of the [] into the GET request.

A similar solution was noted in the answer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322252/1866964

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did with the $http provider:

```
$http({
    url:'api/api.asp',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        client_status: ["CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER", "CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE"],
        client_reference: "e"
    }
}).then(function (result) {
    $scope.test = result.data;
});
```

The call to the server becomes:

```
api/api.asp?client_reference=e&client_status=%5B%22CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER%22%2C%22CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE%22%5D
```

And on the server (here is classic asp vbscript):

```
<%
    Response.Write Request.QueryString("client_status")
%>
```

Which displays:

```
["CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER","CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE"]
```

And you can use it as a normal array.

**EDIT:** It should be very similar with the $resource provider:

```
$resource('api/api.asp', {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            client_status: ["CLIENT_STATUS_FORMER", "CLIENT_STATUS_ACTIVE"],
            client_reference: "e"
        }
    }
);
```